# Problem with accessing image folder in Laravel

Tags: laravel

How can i access public folder image?
I imported a folder from the internet and it is not letting me implement the codes.
I am not seeing the folder images, what is the mistake?

Comment: It has something to do with the permissions of folder, what os are you using right now? For linux you can use this command `sudo chmod -R 777 <folder-name-here>`

Comment: ls -lah in the terminal and check permissions.  Compare it to the other files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the public folder imported in your laravel by using:

asset() method in your blade, for example

```
<img src="{{ asset('img.jpg') }}" alt="">
```